# Is it ever a good idea to break encapsulation?

Tags: c++, class, oop, encapsulation

I am just starting to learn about encapsulation, and I stumbled upon two functions used by std::string that seems to break its encapsulation.

Regarding c_str() and data() from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/ and               http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/data/

"The pointer returned points to the internal array currently used by the string object to store the characters that conform its value".

For someone just learning about OO programming, is it ever a good idea to break encapsulation? 
How about for someone who is more advanced?

As an aside, it seems like this is different behavior from C++98. Why do you believe that they made these changes?

Thanks  for your time.

Comment: Where does that quotation come from? It doesn't appear to come from the referenced links.

Comment: It is under the C++11 tab in the description of both functions.

Comment: Perfect abstractions do not exist in the real world

Comment: This surely belongs on Programmers.SE

Comment: See edit on my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I stumbled upon two functions used by std::string that seem to break its encapsulation.*

Your examples are not violations of the rules on encapsulation:

***The C++ Programming Language, Fourth Edition, Bjarne Stroustrup:***

> !2.5. Pointer to Function
>
> There is no implicit conversion of a string to a char*. That was tried
>   in many places and found to be error-prone. Instead, the standard
>   library provides the explicit conversion function c_str() to const
>   char*.

The same is applicable to `string::data()`. What that means is that the STL has given you a discreet, **read-only** interface through which to extract the data stored within a `std::string`. That is not a violation of encapsulation - the internal data remains hidden behind a discreet interface and cannot be modified. A violation of encapsulation would be if the internal *array of char* stored within the string object was directly exposed for manipulation by making it public, or part of the global namespace, or through an implicit conversion of a `string` to a `char*` and vice versa.

**Having said that:**

> Is it ever a good idea to break encapsulation?

It is never a good idea to follow any programming model **religiously**, if your goal is to create working applications in the real world.

Consider every programming "rule" laid out by every programming paradigm and model and approach, etc etc, as a **guideline**, **a best practice**, once you leave the classroom.

**Extreme Example:** You have deployed a complex application into production, and a bug surfaces. You have one hour to fix the bug, or you lose your job and your firm loses a client. (Yes, such situations do occur - been there, done that...). You can put in a quick fix that will violate the rules of encapsulation, but will have your system up and running again in half an hour. Or, to abide by the rules of encapsulation, you can take two days to refactor your application, carefully modify 500 lines of code, deploy the new version to your test group and hopefully have a patched version ready in two weeks. What to do?

The answer is quite clear: For the moment at least, you're going to break the rules of encapsulation, put in that quick and dirty fix, and get your system up and running again.

Once that's taken care of, you can sit down, think things through, discuss it with your co-workers and managers, and decide if there is indeed a significant ROI in taking out the two weeks to maintain the rules of encapsulation.

**You can be sure of one thing:** If you're working in a business environment and people are making their living by delivering working software, the decision will **not** be dictated by the rules of OOP outlined in some textbook, but by **the business's bottom line**.

Answer (score 3):

While sometimes utility and backwards compatibility overrides the desire for encapsulation like Mahmoud mentions don't let the C++ standard library be validation for breaking encapsulation lightly. This particular point has been contentious and even a source of bugs within many code bases. The problem with `c_str` is that it opens up bad memory corruption by people abusing the returned pointer value or holding on to it for too long after modifying the string which is considered undefined behavior, but neither the compiler nor the runtime environment can enforce that restriction, so in this case the C++ committee chose convenience over safety, and that tradeoff should not be made without considerable justification.

Comment: Very true and thank you for bringing that important point up!

Answer (score 2):

The thing about programming is, you're never inside your own world dealing with just your own code. You have to write code to bring together various pieces and components, and your code needs to be able to do that.

`string`s are awesome, there's no doubt about it. But they are an abstraction - they provide a nice, elegant, easy, and useful way to create and interact with bytes representing textual data in the memory. At the end of the day, as awesome and splendid as a `string` is, it boils down to text. ASCII, UTF-8, whatever, it's text. It would be dandy if everyone could use `std::string` and you could talk to me in `std::string` and I could talk to you in `std::string` and we could all live together happily and merrily. But unfortunately, we live in the real world and that's not the case.

Sooner or later, you're going to find yourself integrating with C APIs that expect plain text. (What's plain text? No one can agree. But basically, a pointer to ASCII/UTF8/UTF16/etc-encoded array of bytes in the memory somewhere). They'll ask for a `const char *data` and all you'll have is your fancy-schmancy `std::string`. Oh no.

That's when you'll realize that your encapsulation is fine and dandy, but in order to have your code actually *do something* and *be useful* you'll need to be able to make it accessible in a common data format, for your sake and for others. And so you'll develop a little helper member function `.c_str()` or `.c_int()` that will make accessible the core feature of your dainty, encapsulated class so that people can read/write from/to it as needed, without needing to be forced to use the same encapsulation technique you worked so long and hard to make.

Especially when dealing with such primitive data types as integers and character arrays, you'll find that fancy encapsulating types will often be eschewed by API developers even when they're using the same language/tools as you. Don't be surprised when you find C++ APIs that take or return `char *` instead of `std::string`. Sometimes they have good reasons (good luck trying to get a `std::string` compiled with one compiler/standard library to actually match up correctly without segfaulting the heck out of your system to your code compiled with a different, non-ABI-compatible library!), sometimes they want to "simplify" their API to the bare minimum so it'll work with consumers from other environments, and sometimes they'll have no reason at all.

Comment: *"It would be dandy if everyone could use std::string and you could talk to me in std::string and I could talk to you in std::string"* I don't think this is necessarily a good idea. IMHO you should only pass around containers if you need to modify the structure of the data. If you only need to read the data, or modify it (inplace), you should use an abstraction like pointers, iterators, ranges, views, .. that reduces the amount of requirements on the argument.

Comment: @dyp: agreed, sorry, I posted my answer by accident while I was still composing it (tab + space). I actually mentioned an extreme nightmare case illustrating why passing around `std::string` doesn't always make sense.

Comment: I'm not sure if we agree completely. `std::string` does not just encapsulate a pointer; it combines an allocation scheme, an allocator and manages a contiguous sequence of characters (an array). For many functions, you don't need all of those. E.g. to find a character in the string, you only need a way to iterate over the characters; the allocator and allocation scheme are irrelevant. By eliminating unused requirements, you can write more generic code.

Comment: Although the OP's question is a good one, I believe the `string::c_str()` example cited is not correct - `c_str()` and `data()` do not violate the rules of encapsulation. I edited my answer to that effect.